# APEX APP(CHANGE PASSWORD): Password not being compared to what is in a Table

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a table called CSD_USERS in APEX Object Browser:

```
  ID         NUMBER         
USERNAME     VARCHAR2(250)  
PASSWORD     VARCHAR2(15)   
ACCESS_TYPE  NUMBER
```

**NOTE: PASSWORD field is populated already.**

A List in Shared Components\List\List Details called **Change Password** with **Parent List Entry set to &APP_USER.**

A created page called Change Password that has 3 Items with Validations using PL/SQL Code:

P14_OLD_PASSWORD

```
Declare
v_pass Varchar2(30);
Begin
  select PASSWORD into v_pass from CSD_USERS
    where ID = :APP_USER
    and Password = :P14_OLD_PASSWORD;

    RETURN TRUE;
    
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
         RETURN FALSE;
end;
```

P14_NEW_PASSWORD

```
BEGIN
IF 5 <= LENGTH(:P14_NEW_PASSWORD) AND  LENGTH(:P14_NEW_PASSWORD) <= 15  THEN
    IF REGEXP_LIKE(:P14_NEW_PASSWORD, '^.*[0-9]') THEN
 IF REGEXP_LIKE(:P14_NEW_PASSWORD, '^.*[a-z]', 'c') THEN
 IF REGEXP_LIKE(:P14_NEW_PASSWORD, '^.*[A-Z]', 'c') THEN
 IF REGEXP_LIKE(:P14_NEW_PASSWORD, '^.*[!@#$%^&*()_]', 'c') THEN
 RETURN '';
 ELSE
    RETURN 'Password must have a special character';
 END IF;
 ELSE
    RETURN 'Password must have at least one uppercase character';
 END IF;   
 ELSE
    RETURN 'Password must have at least one lowercase character';
 END IF;
 ELSE
    RETURN 'Password must have at least one numeric value';
 END IF; 
ELSE
RETURN 'Password length must be 5 or grater then 5
, Your password length is'||' '||LENGTH(:P14_NEW_PASSWORD);
END IF;
END;
```

P14_RETYPE_NEW_PASSWORD_VALIDATION

```
V('P14_NEW_PASSWORD') = 
V('P14_RETYPE_NEW_PASSWORD')
```

Change Password Page also has a process called CHANGE_PASSWORD_PROCESS

```
BEGIN
  UPDATE CSD_USERS
  SET PASSWORD = :P14_NEW_PASSWORD
  WHERE ID = :APP_USER
  AND PASSWORD = :P14_OLD_PASSWORD;
END;
```

The issue is that when I go to test It keeps saying that the Old Password doesn't (Error Message that was defined) match even though I'm copying/typing the same thing.

Is there something I am missing that is causing an issue with the comparison of the Old Password I signed in with vs the Old Password I'm providing when trying to change to a new password?

Comment: This: `where ID = :APP_USER` looks suspicious. ID is declared as NUMBER, while APP_USER (usually) looks like "Omatayo" or "Littlefoot" or something like that, so - are you sure that it is about the *old password* value, and not wrong comparison I mentioned?

Comment: Based on what  you mentioned, what should I compare with "ID" to match the user before I change password, P14_ID?

Comment: Compare USERNAME to APP_USER.

Comment: Made the change but it still isn't working. Comparing USERNAME = :APP_USER. And also, there's no error popping up with regards to the page or anything. Just displaying my message Old Password is Incorrect

Comment: It didn't work when I said ID = :P14_ID either

Comment: Could you post some sample data? We don't know what you really have in that table, nor how you created usernames or their passwords.

Comment: Okay, so one of the records with ID = 2, USERNAME = anforde, PASSWORD = anforde. These information were entered manually.

Comment: The other fundamental issue here that may be related - your code doesn't do any hashing of the passwords, it's presuming they're stored as clear text. This is bad practice. You're also reinventing the wheel with your validation procedure, as Oracle has libraries for this as well.

Comment: I agree with @Scott, but - perhaps we'd first make it work, then make it fancy. Omatayo, values you posted are in lowercase. When you run the application and connect to it, what does the upper-right corner say? Is username written in upper, or lower case? If UPPER, you'll have to match these two, so apply either UPPER or LOWER function against these values in your function.

Comment: instrument your code: put debug statements in the procedures so you can see what values are being interpreted and then run the statements manually. Have a look at the ```APEX_DEBUG``` api

Comment: @Littlefoot This may very well be the cause. For all we know, the table already exists with hashed data, and this new APEX application is attempting to utilise it without awareness of the hashing. As Koen suggests, we need some instrumentation to see what values are being compared.

Comment: The CSD_USERS Table only exists as the one I created given the unique app that was built. The data in the table was entered manually (Means I entered it cell by cell in the Username and Password Column) and this code above is supposed to 1. check that the password matches and then 2. Change it with the new password created at the stage of NEW PASSWORD and RETYPE NEW PASSWORD